# React App Firebase Missing or insufficient permissions error when importing data to firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to import this data from my seed.js file and for some reason firebase is giving my this error. I'm not sure if I forgot to install a file or if I am missing a certain script tag in the index.html, but for some reason don't know why it's not working

[image]

Here is my index.js file code

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { GlobalStyles } from './global-styles';
import { App } from './app';
import { FirebaseContext } from './context/firebase';

import { seedDatabase } from './seed';

const config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
};



const firebase = window.firebase.initializeApp(config);
seedDatabase(firebase);

ReactDOM.render(
    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={{ firebase: window.firebase }}>
        <GlobalStyles />
        <App />
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is the seed.js file data

```js
export function seedDatabase(firebase) {
  function getUUID() {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, c => {
      const piece = (Math.random() * 16) | 0;
      const elem = c === 'x' ? piece : (piece & 0x3) | 0x8;
      return elem.toString(16);
    });
  }


  firebase.firestore().collection('series').add({
    id: getUUID(),
    title: 'Something',
    description: 'Example'
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues/508) and [here](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues/494).

> This is caused by using user profile for login with redirection handling enabled. You can workaround it by setting UserProfile to null in the config.
> like

```
 const rrfConfig = {
 userProfile: null,
 ...
 ...
 };
```

> I have not tried setting enableRedirectHandling: false when userProfile is enabled. YOu may have a try too.

And also the error logs are just warnings and don't impact functionality.

Plus, did you call `firebase.auth().signOut()` after `Firebase.logout()`? If so, switch these around.

This may be outdated info since all of this was fixed on Jan 24.

## Also:

This may be caused by the security system of Firebase not allowing you to import data.

Comment: what are you saying? I don't have any of those for my app. All I need is to import data from seed.js into my firebase database

Answer (score 0):

A `Missing or insufficient permissions error` is occurred by Cloud Firestore Security Rules.

At first, could you check your Cloud Firestore Security Rules?

If you only add document then you should set create rule.

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#basic_readwrite_rules
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics